# Nested ViewModels: Button actions and Communication?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

This is going to be a lengthy question, but I have been dodging this problem a long time by building ugly big all-in-one classes.

As an example, I am writing a WPF standalone application with MVVM design (am also using Caliburn.Micro), and have a `MainViewModel` with a `MainView`. This view contains a `StackPanel`, and the contents of this `StackPanel` is bound to a ViewModel `CentralVM`:

```
<StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">
     <ContentControl Margin="10" Name="CentralVM"/>
</StackPanel>
```

In the `MainViewModel` class, I have a couple of other ViewModels,

```
private PropertyChangedBase _centralVM = new PropertyChangedBase();        
private LoggedInViewModel _loggedInVM = new LoggedInViewModel();
private LoginViewModel _logInVM = new LoginViewModel();

public PropertyChangedBase CentralVM {
    get { return _centralVM; }
    set { _centralVM = value; NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CentralVM); }
}
public LoggedInViewModel LoggedInVM {
    get { return _loggedInVM; }
    private set { _loggedInVM = value; }
}
public LoginViewModel LoginVM {
    get { return _logInVM; }
    private set { _loginVM = value;}
}
```

Now, in the Constructor of the `MainViewModel` I set

```
CentralVM = LoginVM
```

and then the `StackPanel` is automatically bound the View `LoginView`. The `LoginView` does what you would guess, namely you can enter (username, pwd), and there is a button that evaluates the entries and in case it is correct, I want to switch set the `CentralVM` to `LoggedInVM`. But the button event 'lives' in the `LoginVM` instance of the `LoginViewModel`, so how do I access the Property `CentralVM` in the `MainViewModel`?

This is of course only an example of a general kind of problem. My first idea was to do the following:

-The `LoginVM` contains a property (of type string) called `LoggedInAs` that is set when the button in clicked.
-I add a method to `MainViewModel`, like so:

```
private _loggedIn = false;
private void CheckForLoginChange() {
    if (_loggedIn == false && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(LoginVM.LoggedInAs)) {
        _loggedIn = true; 
        CentralVM = LoggedInVM;
    }
}
```

-Finally, I add this method call to the setter of the `LoginVM`, i.e.,

```
public LoginViewModel LoginVM {
    get { return _logInVM; }
    private set { _logInVM = value; CheckForLoginChange(); }
}
```

But this does not work. Is it because although the `LoginVM` changes when the button event is clicked, the setter is not called?

Grateful for any help in this direction. I would very much appreciate a detailed answer and not only some buzzword references to 'EventAggregators' or 'Messengers' - I know they have something to do with possible solutions, but I have not found good documentation that I could understand...

Comment: I don't completely understand, but why you are not using a Command for the button click?

Comment: Because I see no reason to, Caliburn.Micro wires the Button to a method of same name as the button automatically. What would the be the advantage of using a command here? It would not resolve my problem, or?

Comment: Ok I'm just not familiar with caliburn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, it is exactly the job for Event Aggregator. You have one in Caliburn.Micro, built in.

It's quite easy, both the `MainViewModel` and `LoginViewModel` should take the aggregator as a dependency:

```
private readonly IEventAggregator eventAggregator;
public MainViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
{
    this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    this.eventAggregator.Subscribe(this);
}
```

Same goes for the `LoginViewModel`. A little warning here, they both should receive the *same* instance of event aggregator, so the events are propagated correctly (actually, it might be actually best to set the IoC container to inject `IEventAggregator` as singleton).

Now the `MainViewModel` should implement `IHandle<T>`, where `T` is the class that will serve as a message, let's say:

```
public class LogInSuccessful
{
    public readonly string LoggedInAs;
    public LogInSuccessful(string loggedInAs)
    {
        LoggedInAs = loggedInAs;
    }
}
```

then

```
public class MainViewModel : ... , IHandle<LogInSuccessful>
{
    ....
    public void Handle(LogInSuccessful message)
    {
        //here you can change the VM and access message.LoggedInAs string. 
        //This method will be called when there's an appropriate event published
        //to the same event aggregator that the MainViewModel is subscribed to.
    }
}
```

To publish the event, you have to get a hold of event aggregator inside the `LoginViewModel` and then at some point call:

```
eventAggregator.Publish(new LogInSuccessful("Admin"));
```

---

Further edit

That way, the `LoginViewModel` does one thing only - validates the credentials. If they're valid, it publishes the event to the `MainViewModel`, which manages the screens and should take an appropriate action. `LoginViewModel` shouldn't 'manually' change any of the screens on the main view model, it's not its job.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but: What is the IoC container? Waht do you mean by 'injectas singleton'? I must admit I have hithereto used Caliburn.Micro as a convenient way to bind via convention but don't understand the deeper features yet - also because I have not found detailed enough documentation and i am not good at learning from examples, I like abstract, complete explanations (I am a mathematician...)

Comment: @ToaoG OK, that is rather related to [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and orthogonal to the question you have right now, but here's a really brief description. IoC is 'Inversion of Control', and the 'IoC container' is a mechanism that wires up the dependencies for you at the start of the application. 'Inject as singleton' means that the mentioned container will return one and the same instance of the object resolved. In this case, it would mean that all objects get the same event aggregator instance.

Comment: So to receive the 'same instance', should I create an instance in the constructor of MainViewModel and then pass this instance into the constructors of the other ViewModels  (which I also execute in the constructor of the MainViewModel)?

Comment: Thanks, and not to be rude, but the descriptive answer of what an IoC container is I have read before, but wht is it exactly? Let me just ask naively: Is it a class, do I have to create an instance? If not, where does it live? etc. I just don't get these general answers, sorry.

Comment: IoC container is an object. In `Caliburn.Micro` it's created in `AppBootstrapper` when the application starts and it resolves all the dependencies (along with the views, view models, other interfaces etc). And yes, you create the container, register the dependencies and leave it be. Then Caliburn.Micro uses it to resolve dependencies 'automatically'. If you don't need it, you can set dependencies 'by hand' in constructors, although in a longer run that might be error-prone and tiresome. Unfortunately there's not enough room here in the comments to go deeper on this topic ;)

Comment: Why do you invent a new class 'LogInsuccessful' that contains only a string, not use IHandle<String> directly?

Comment: @ToaoG Because then 1. It's less descriptive 2. Any other class subscribed to `IHandle<string>` would receive this message, and the strings might convey different messages and meanings, not every class should probably receive it, which takes us back to first point :) It's more of a matter of the application architecture than formal correctness of the code.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please elaborate on how to set up the 'singleton inject eventaggregator' in the 'IoC', because I tried what I suggesten a couple of comments ago to make each viewmodel take an IEventaggregator intance in the consturctor and pass in the one of the MainViewModel, but compilation crases with the error 'could not find parameterless constructor' on the viewmodel classes - although I never call a parameterless constructor...

Comment: @ToaoG [Here's `Caliburn.Micro` AppBootstrapper](http://snipt.org/zfhgc8) using [SimpleInjector](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/). When you request a view model with `IEventAggregator` dependency in the constructor, the IoC will automatically resolve the dependency and inject the instance.

Comment: Thanks again. Will maybe try that later, but having to install yet another framework (SimpleInjector) is not very satisfying, actually scary, because then there will be a large portion in my program that I don't fully understand... Already Caliburn.Micro was a leap for me. I'm probably still too naive and hence too much of a purist to be comfortable with that, still think I should understand every line of code in a program I write...   Will need some time, but Thx again.

Comment: BTW, I think the crashes result from the call of the constructor of the MainViewModel by passing the IEventAggregator eventaggregator, but the bootstrapper class of Caliburn.Micro which creates the MainViewModel tries to find a parameterless constructor for the MainViewModel... How can I resolve that?

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your last comment, you could customise the bootstrapper but to be honest if you aren't going to use the IoC container and aren't interested in that level of abstraction, you can just use a static class to hold an instance of the aggregator.

Of course you are coupled to an implementation but if you are only running a small project and aren't interested in the DI/IoC part, it will do.

Simple class could be

```
static class EventAggregatorProvider 
{ 
    private static EventAggregator _aggregator = new EventAggregator();

    public static EventAggregator Aggregator { get { return _aggregator; } }
}
```

Then in your code just access it via the static class:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    // Do something
    EventAggregatorProvider.Aggregator.Publish(new SomeMessage());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This one I understand completely :-) I have gotten around to customize my bootstrapper and gotten that approach to work, but I will def. try this in my next small project. If it is this simple, why have I never seen this approach before...

Comment: Probably because most people will use the IoC approach because it's the most flexible - but to be honest it's only useful if you are using the benefits that IoC provides - if you aren't interested in using it (especially for small projects) then you don't have to. It also means your code is a bit less flexible as you can't inject a particular implementation of an aggregator and you need the static class to be present when running unit tests rather than just injecting it - meaning you can't run the VM in isolation without the static implementation